# Magento 1.9 - issue creating coupon rule. An error occurred while saving the rule data

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, coupon

I can create a new **Shopping Cart Price Rule**, but when using Actions or Conditions it won't save, resulting in a red error:

> An error occurred while saving the rule data. Please review the log
>         and try again.

Reviewing the exception.log file shows an error about duplicate key in MySql table

```
    EXCEPTION 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8-1-0-160' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /root/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /root/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2100): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#7 /root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2073): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('salesrule_produ...', Array, Array)
#8 /root/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(293): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertMultiple('salesrule_produ...', Array)
#9 /root/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(133): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Rule->setActualProductAttributes(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule), Array)
#10 /root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(463): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Rule->_afterSave(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))
#11 /root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))
#12 /root/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php(163): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#13 /root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController->saveAction()
#14 /root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#15 /root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /root/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /root/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

After much digging and troubleshooting, I found in pdo_mysql.log the exact INSERT INTO query that was generated by the system, and it appears that the first array has an empty value for `customer_group_id` field - which ends up as "0" in MySql (since the filed is NOT NULL), thus resulting in a duplicate key error for the next array!

See below:

```
INSERT INTO `salesrule_product_attribute` 
(`rule_id`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`attribute_id`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?)
BIND: array (
  0 => '8',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '',
  3 => '160',
  4 => '8',
  5 => '1',
  6 => '0',
  7 => '160',
  8 => '8',
  9 => '1',
  10 => '1',
  11 => '160',
  12 => '8',
  13 => '1',
  14 => '2',
  15 => '160',
  16 => '8',
  17 => '1',
  18 => '3',
  19 => '160',
)
```

I have not touched the Customer Groups in Magento, only got the 4 default groups that are 0 1 2 3.

So why is this extra empty array generated, and how do I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

the error is being generated by a catch block inside this class: 
**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Promo/QuoteController.php**
at line 184 .

```
Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('An error occurred while saving the rule data. Please review the log and try again.'));
```

you could add an $e->getMessage() to the error output if you are not on a production server and then you will know what was the problem.
Good luck and happy coding !!!

Comment: thank you for pointing that out.  $e->getMessage() only shows the error of "Duplicate entry '8-1-0-160' for key 'PRIMARY'", which I already knew. I'd love to know the cause of the error too ;) that is why the extra empty array value is generated.